# Problema Expresion regular

Tags: sql, regex

Buenas necesito sacar unos numero de unas cadena de texto y no consigo sacar la expresión regular que necesito aquí el ejemplo.

> **Hola que tal #4702665**
>
> **Bienvenido 45454545 tal #470815 BD. WA470815**

Necesito solo estos números: ***#470815 #4702665*** en esas dos frases pero sin la almohadilla lo demás que me lo descarte todo.

```
SELECT comment, type, comment as numero FROM Transicion WHERE comment REGEXP '#[0-9]+'
```

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme gracias.

He conseguido con esto conseguirlo pero no me sirve para mi DB ya que usa mysql5.7 alguien sabe alguna solucion para poder aplicarlo a mi DB

```
 SELECT id, comment, SUBSTRING(comment, '#([0-9]+)') AS user_id
 FROM transiction;
```

Alguna idea para aplicar eso mismo a mysql 5.7??

---

haciéndolo con sql REGEXP '#[0-9]+' lo que hace es contarme el numero de veces que ese patrón coincide, yo lo que necesito es que me muestre ese valor. alguna ayuda por favor?

Comment: Por favor indica desde que lenguaje usas las expresiones regulares ya que hay diferencias en cuanto a la implementación. Saludos.

Comment: es para una extraccion en sql

Comment: Por favor indica el motor de SQL que estás usando, las expresiones regulares varían mucho de [tag:mysql] a [tag:postgresql] por ejemplo

Comment: Acá podrás hallar algunas soluciones usando el motor de postgresql https://www.codewars.com/kata/sql-easy-regex-extraction/sql

Comment: Buenas el motor que estoy usando es mysql ver 5.6

Comment: y el motor es InnoDB

Comment: **DUDA-1**: Utilizas algún lenguaje de programación para hacer las consultas? (por ejemplo php), o haces las consultas directamente sobre la BBDD (por ejemplo, con algún cliente de mysql). **DUDA-2**: los datos en la columna comment pueden tener más de una vez el patrón `#numero`? (Por ejemplo: `Hola #123456 y adios #987654`). **DUDA-3** Si quieres quitar todo lo que no sean esos patrones (también almohadillas), para el caso anterior `Hola #123456 y adios #987654` te quedaría `123456987654` (todo junto) y no se sabría muy bien si es un número o dos juntos. Eres consciente? Es lo que necesitas?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con algo como:

```
"#[0-9]+" //matchea el número con el símbolo "#"

"(?<=#)[0-9]+" //matchea sólo el número (cuidado, puede no ser soportada en todos los navegadores)
```

puedes probar las expresión en [este](https://regexr.com/) sitio

Comment: Es justo lo contrario a eso lo que busco eso me corta el numero necesito al reves que me cortelo demas y me deje solo el numero.

Comment: Puedes tomar ese valor y sacarle el primer caracter (el numeral) y quedarte con el número.

Comment: me puede poner un ejemplo como el anterior?? me cuesta muchísimo las expresiones regulares, gracias

Comment: Ahí edité mi respuesta. En la segúnda se utiiza el concepto de `positive Lookbehind` [+info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: esta ultima es perfecta es tal cual quiero, pero en el programa que estoy utilizando lo que hace es lo contrario me quita lo que quiero y me deja lo que es justo al reves. y no se ejecutarla en sql directamente

Comment: Tienes que ofrecer más información en tu pregunta entonces, si no es difícil ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: tengo un comentario como el que mostré antes en un campo de una columna sql, y mi intención es pasarlo a otro campo pero solo ese numero que quiero seleccionar.

Comment: esta sentencia REGEXP '#[0-9]+ me muestra el numero de veces que encuentro ese match entre todas mis columnas yo necesito que me ponga el string de esa cadena que cumple ese valor.

Comment: Puedes poner algún bloque de código de lo qué estás haciendo? así es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: SELECT
comment,
type,
comment as numero
FROM
Transicion
WHERE
AND comment REGEXP  '#[0-9]+'

Comment: ese es el bloque que uso y yo lo que hace es mostrarme en la columa numero los que cumple esa condicione que le he puesto y me repite, y yo necesito en esa columna el numero extraido con la expresion regular.